# Users locked out from DC, automatically unlocked by administrator

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, domain-controller, user-accounts

I am working on a typical windows architecture containing DCs, Exchange servers, etc...
Recently I set up a script to receive a notification whenever a user get locked out. It works prefectly, however I noticed something very odd.
I report several information, like the machine from where the user has been locked out, the DC responsible for the action, etc... (I can get all these information in logs on the DCs. ID 4740 for locked out, 4767 for unlock). 
The thing is that regularly (about 1 or 2 each day), some users get locked ou from a Domain Controller (like if he had failed his password multiple times on this DC). Of course, users can't access the DCs, so that is the first strange thing. More strange is that these users get automatically unlocked by Administrator about 1 second later.
Do you know what might cause this ? I'm pretty sure it cannot be anything malicious.
Note that :

- It's impossible users get access to the DCs (or I have a really really good hacker hidden among them, and I don't know how he would be able to do that ^^)
- Locked out users are never the same, it seems to be random
- The delay between lock out and unlock is so short (a bit less than 1 sec) that a human would need to be ready to unlock the account as soon as it is locked out, so it has to be done automatically
- Locked out users from their computers stay locked out, as they should stay. Automatic unlock happens only when the lock out event is done from a DC.
- Administrator account is never used nor referenced in any way for the script call/execution

Thanks for your time ! :)

---

Here is the code of the script (however I don't think it can be of any use)

```
#Get security user lockout events.  61 seconds should be sufficient, as the scheduled task run every minute.
#It leaves 1 sec for execution time.
#EventID 4740 is user lockout. 4767 is unlock.

$startTime = (get-date).addseconds(-61)

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$DomainControllers = (Get-ADDomainController -Filter *)

foreach ($DC in $DomainControllers) {

    $eventList = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $DC.Name -filterhashtable @{logname="security";starttime=$startTime;id="4740"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $emailBody = $null

    if ($eventList) {

        #Start a walk through the events to collect data.

        $eventList | foreach-object {
            [string]$lockoutTime = $_.timecreated
            $userName = $_.Properties[0].Value
            $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $userName -Properties *
            $name = $user.Name
            $department = $user.Department
            $site = $user.City
            $mail = $user.PrimarySmtpAddress
            $userSID = $_.Properties[2].Value
            $computerName = $_.Properties[1].Value -creplace '^\\+',''
            $IPAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($computerName).IPAddressToString

            #Compile the alert text from each event

            $emailBody += "Utilisateur : $name`nDepartment : $department`nSite : $site`nLogin : $userName`nEmail : $mail`nOrdinateur fautif : $computerName`nAdresses IP : $IPAddress`nDate de verrouillage : $lockoutTime`nDC responsable du verrouillage : $($DC.Name)`nSID de l'utilisateur : $userSID"

            #Send mail to report the lockout
            Send-MailMessage -To "<####>" -From "<####>" -Subject "Blocage compte AD" -Body $emailBody -SmtpServer "####"


            #Create a popup on desktop
            $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
            $objForm.Text = "Unlocked AD accounts"
            $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,115) 
            $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

            $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
            $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
            $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,15) 
            $objLabel.Text = "Compte de $name verrouillé."
            $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)

            $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
            $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,50)
            $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(85,23)
            $OKButton.Text = "Tant pis"
            $OKButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
            $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

            $UnlockButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
            $UnlockButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,50)
            $UnlockButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(85,23)
            $UnlockButton.Text = "Déverrouiller"
            $UnlockButton.Add_Click({Unlock-ADAccount $userName; $objForm.Close()})
            $objForm.Controls.Add($UnlockButton)
            if ((Get-ADUser $userName -Properties Lockedout).Lockedout) {
                [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might not be able to answer your questions today, but I'll be here tomorrow !

Comment: Hi, is it a script you can add to the question? as its maybe the script that do that. As builtin windows dont reactivate automaticly an account.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Yeah that is why it concerns me... I'm pretty sure it is not the script, as all it is doing is checking DC's logs. Even if it managed somehow to lockout someone, why would it be a random user ? And why would it be unlocked by administrator ? Oh yeah, I have forgot to precise that administrator account is never used during script call/execution. I'll add that to the question

Comment: @yagmoth I'll add my script to the question, just for information, though I don't think this is relevant.

Comment: You are right the script seem ok, what is your default domain policy for password? I ask as login on the DC are show for user login on their PC, thus a policy to unlock after a short time can exist

Comment: @yagmoth555 Yes I first thought about that too, but I checked the policy for automatic unlock, and it is set to more than 1400 minutes. I didn't see anything else in the policies that could be related, but I might have missed one. By the way, thanks for trying ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you were still looking for the answer 11 months later, typically the cause of the "Caller Computer Name" being a Domain Controller, is that that particular DC is the one reporting the lockout.

DC1 has event 4740 saying that a user account was locked out reported from DC2.

If you go to DC2 and look for the same 4740 event, you will see that the "Caller Computer Name" now says the actual computer the user was locked out from.

I've had events coming from my on-site Exchange server and this confused me the same way you did, until I logged into the exchange server and looked for the same lockout events and saw where they were coming from.

The automatic unlock is probably DC2 unlocking the account after the default 30 minute lockout delay, and reporting it to DC1.

Answer (score 0):

It might be like its a service account as in most default policies service account automatically gets unlocked if it gets locked. I have observed the same in my environment. Hope that helps & if you have any inputs/suggestions.Feel free to share

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Accounts are not necessarily service accounts (actually I have not seen any service account locked out), they seem to be random user accounts in the domain. I have stopped investigating this, since it is not really a problem, but more a weird behaviour that might just relate to the logs. If you have any more ideas, I am interested, though ! :)